# how to create and process a saml assertion in java?

Tags: java, opensaml

i'm beginner in opensaml-j and i want to create an assertion to delegate capabilities i have the assertion written in SAML, here's the image: [SAML-based representation of capability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NkuX.png)

so can someone help me to create the assertion shown in the image with opensaml-j
and how to process this latter??

Answer (score 1):

So one approach of **creating assertion** is to:

```
AuthnRequest authnRequest = new AuthnRequestBuilder().buildObject();
```

Set the mandatory attributes of your SAML 2.0 Request. It is up to you to decide what goes in your SAML request.

```
authnRequest.setID(<>));
authnRequest.setVersion(SAMLVersion.VERSION_20);
authnRequest.setIssueInstant(new DateTime());

authnRequest.setProtocolBinding(httpBinding);
authnRequest.setIssuer(issuer);
authnRequest.setNameIDPolicy(nameIdPolicy);
authnRequest.setRequestedAuthnContext(requestedAuthnContext);
authnRequest.setDestination(idpUrl);
```

Before you send it you may want to sign it, this is done by adding a signature to your request.

Once you receive a SMAL response you could validate it by verifying its signature:

```
// Signature validation
Signature signature = samlResponse.getSignature();
SignatureValidator signatureValidator = new SignatureValidator(
new X509CredentialImplementation(<>);

try {
    signatureValidator.validate(signature);
} catch (ValidationException e) {
    LOGGER.error("XML signature is not **validate**, or there is an error during the validation operation");
  return false;
}
```

It is not clear how and where you want to send the assertion. But this is the basic procedure.

- Create the request. Send it.
- Wait for a response from service provider or whatever.
- Validate the signature of the response.
- If is valid response, you can grant necessary permission to the user.

Comment: thanks for your help i really appriciate it i just want to ask you about the other tags (Condtion,Action,AuthzDecisionStatement) how am i going to create them ?? can you give me a more detailed example please??